# Haskell - fmap for a tree with variable number of nodes in

Tags: haskell, tree, functor

I have this data type definition :

```
data RoseTree a = Leaf a | Branch [RoseTree a] deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I need to write the fmap Functor

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I started with

```
fmap f (Leaf a) =  Leaf (f a)
fmap f (Branch [] ) =  Branch []
fmap f (Branch (x:xs) ) =   ??? -- stuck here
```

But now I'm stuck and can't make progress - hope someone can guide me.
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: you need to apply `f` to each element of the list.

Comment: But how do I do that ?

Comment: Do you know the `map` function? Or list comprehensions?

Comment: Yes I do I just don't know how to make the Haskell type system happy

Comment: You actually need to recursively apply `fmap f` to each subtree

Answer (score 2):

The general structure of a recursive function on a `RoseTree` is

```
forestFun :: [RoseTree a] -> r
forestFun [] = _
forestFun (xs : xss) = _
    where recXs = treeFun xs
          recXss = forestFun xss

treeFun :: RoseTree a -> r
treeFun (Leaf x) = _
treeFun (Branch xss) = forestFun xss
```

The reason it's two functions and not one is because `RoseTree` is really two data types and not one. Notice that the data type `RoseTree` doesn't actually recurse to itself, but to lists of trees (which are called "forests"). They are two data types defined in terms of each other, which makes them inseparable.

```
type Forest a = [RoseTree a]
-- data Forest a = [] | (:) (RoseTree a) (Forest a)
data RoseTree a = Leaf a | Branch (Forest a)
```

Often, `forestFun` will be hidden away as a `where` clause inside `treeFun`. Further, since `RoseTree` doesn't actually mention `RoseTree` (but `Forest` mentions both), you can merge the two functions in a somewhat ugly manner:

```
treeFun :: RoseTree a -> r
treeFun (Leaf x) = _
treeFun (Branch []) = _
treeFun (Branch (x : xs)) = _
     where recXs = treeFun (Branch xs)
```

This is ugly because you often (including in this case) need to use a partial pattern match on `recXs` to extract useful information. I would recommend taking the first template and modifying it to implement your function. You could also use the second template (in which case, you should think about what kind of partial pattern match you need to do on `recXs`). Afterwards, you can simplify your function in terms of `fmap` (as shown in the other answer), but it is important to understand why you need two recursive functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code works

```
 instance Functor RoseTree where
  fmap f (Leaf a) =  Leaf (f a)
  fmap f (Branch xs ) =  Branch (map (fmap f) xs)
```

I'm still trying to understand why.

Comment: Each element of `xs` is a `RoseTree`. `fmap f` is the function that applies `f` to each element *in* a `RoseTree`, and `map` is how you apply that function to each `RoseTree` in the list.

Comment: list comprehensions are visual, might be easier to code with: `fmap f (Branch ts) = Branch [fmap f t | t <- ts]`. also, use mnemonic var naming to ease the cognitive load, i.e. use `ts` for "trees".

Comment: ... i.e., "for each tree `t :: RoseTree a` in the trees `ts :: [RoseTree a]`, replace `t` with `fmap f t`". which is a *recursive* call to `fmap (f :: a -> b) :: RoseTree a -> RoseTree b`. since each `t` is `t :: RoseTree a`, `fmap f` *applies* (i.e. *can* be applied; so we indeed apply it!), transforming `RoseTree a` into `RoseTree b`. It helps to include the specific type for `fmap` in the specific instance, either as a comment of with the language extension `InstanceSigs`: `fmap :: (a -> b) -> RoseTree a -> RoseTree b`.

Comment: [`InstanceSigs` link](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#instance-signatures-type-signatures-in-instance-declarations).